# What is the historical purpose of the email trash folder (email service providers)?

Tags: email, gmail

I notice that on many email service providers (gmail/yahoo) that it is common to have the usual (inbox/sent/trash) folders.

Although it makes sense to divide emails received from emails sent, what exactly is the point of moving "deleted" files just to another folder?

Sometimes, they sit there permanently while other times they are garbage collected at random times (while in the folder), and sometimes they can only be "actually deleted" after they have been moved to the trash folder!

was this behaviour due to a legacy technological limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opinions might differ here depending on who you are asking, but I would say it is due to legacy rather than technological limitations.

The "move to trash" flow of deleting items are common in other applications as well, not least file handling in MS Windows and Mac OSX.

Since emails in this case (gmail/yahoo mail) can be deleted with only one click or action, the trash folder gives the user a way to regret deleting an item or restore it after accidental deletion of an item. The same argument for the "move to trash" flow is valid for file handling in MS Windows and Mac OSX as well for example.